# Simplist proof you have for the Monty Hall Problem

Tags: no-computers, monty-hall

This sounds simple. What is the easiest solution to the Monty Hall problem you have which does not use listing out every probability and also **requires you use algorithms?** Also, no research or computers.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "requires you use algorithms"?

Comment: Some explanations here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/96826/the-monty-hall-problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> When you switch, if you had the car selected before, you now get a goat.  If you had a goat selected, the other is revealed, so you now get the car.  Thus, *the probabilities after switching are exactly equal to the reverse of your original probabilities*.
>
>  You originally had a $\frac13$ chance of getting the car, so switching gives you a $\frac23$ chance.  Not switching leaves your original odds unchanged, at $\frac13$.
>
>  The generalization of this would be for a Monty Hall problem with $x$ doors, of which one is the "winning" door.  After your initial guess, all but one other door is revealed.  In this case, your initial guess has $\frac1x$ odds of being right, while switching has $1-\frac1x$ odds.  As a result, switching improves your odds by $1-\frac2x$.  Note that, for all $x > 2$, this is a positive change.

Comment: The answer, but I would like to see an algorithm proving it, not just that.

Comment: Could you possibly think of something else? Yesterday when I tried to explain that to someone, they didn't want to listen...

Comment: Added a generalization, which allows for a more mathematical formulation of the result.

Answer (score 6):

You have a:

> $\frac13$ chance of picking the correct door, Monty'll show you one of the other doors, you switch and lose.
>  $\frac23$ chance of picking a wrong door, Monty'll show you the *other* wrong door, you switch and win.

EDIT: Now I have better understanding of what you've after.
You have a robot:

> Preprogrammed to *always* swap.
>  First move: Get rid of a door at random.  Say that as pick to Monty.
>  Second move: Get rid of door Monty shows.
>  Last move: Pick remaining door.
>  Now Monty will never show a winning door.
>  So the second move never gets rid of a win.
>  So the only way to lose is if the robot randomly picks the winning door in the first move with probably $\frac13$.
>  And therefore the probability of a win is $1 - \frac13 = \frac23$